# Error received while using IndexToString Function in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, feature-engineering

I received the following error when trying to convert the encoded customer_id and product_id columns:

```
an error occurred while calling o2516.transform. :
java.lang.classcastexception: 
org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.unresolvedattribute$ cannot be cast to 
org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.nominalattribute.
```

The code snippet related to the issue is as follows:

```
indexer = [StringIndexer(inputCol=column, outputCol=column+"_index") for column in ['customer_id', 'product_id']]
pipeline = Pipeline(stages=indexer)
transformed = pipeline.fit(df2).transform(df2)

(training, test) = transformedDF.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

als= ALS(maxIter=5, rank=4, regParam=0.01,userCol='customer_id_index', itemCol='product_id_index', \
                ratingCol='star_rating', coldStartStrategy='drop',\
                nonnegative=True)

model=als.fit(training)

predictions=model.transform(test)

evaluator=RegressionEvaluator(metricName='rmse',labelCol='star_rating',predictionCol='prediction')
rmse=evaluator.evaluate(predictions)

print(rmse)

recommendations=model.recommendForAllUsers(10)

recs=recommendations.withColumn("itemAndRating",explode(recommendations.recommendations))\
.select("customer_id_index","itemAndRating.*")

customerConverter=IndexToString(inputCol="customer_id_index",outputCol="customer_id",labels=customerIndexer.labels)
productConverter=IndexToString(inputCol="product_id_index",outputCol="product_id",labels=productIndexer.labels)

results=Pipeline(stages=[customerConverter,productConverter]).fit(transformed).transform(recs)
```

Here is the screenshot of what data looks like:

[image]

I am expecting it to convert the encoded product_id and customer_id values back to the original. I am not certain where I went wrong but your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can be closed. After creating the model, I reviewed the data type of each column and realized that customer_id_index and product_id_index were of type string. So what I did was to convert them to a double (the original data type) and then it worked.
The code is as follows:

```
recs=recs.withColumn("customer_id_index",col("customer_id_index").cast("double")).\ withColumn("product_id_index",col("product_id_index").cast("double"))
```